# How to get maximal position of product in a category in Magento 1?

Tags: magento-1.9, category, sql, position

I want to get the maximal position assigned to a product in the category , so that whenever I create a new product then I can assign ($max+1) position to the product and it will be displayed in the end of the page in frontend.

Can anyone help me how to get maximal product position for a single category in Magento1?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For get the maximum position of product in a category :

```
$categoryId = '175';
$model = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($categoryId)->getProductsPosition(); //get the positions of all product in magento for a category

echo max($test); // check for maximum value in array
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
<?php 
$maxPosition = Mage::getSingleton('catalog/layer')
    ->setCurrentCategory(Mage::registry('current_category'))
    ->getProductCollection()
    ->getMaxPosition(); 
?>
```

Comment: I am getting this error : Call to undefined method Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Product_Collection::getMaxPosition() . It's not working